# Python Google Slides API - Adjust table width and height to fit inside the page

Tags: python-3.x, google-slides-api

My goal:

- I want to create a new table inside the Google Slides for the specified page_id
- Adjust the table column width and row height so the whole table would fit in a single page.
- I want to achieve above using python

Known limitations:

- slides api documentation states that minimum column width can be 406400 (EMU) or 32 PT. **These are too big for the table I need.**
- Sending a request with values lower than above, will make no change to a table in the presentation.

My questions:

1. Is there a way to undermine the column width min value?
2. How can I create a table that maximises the page "real estate"?

Answer (score 0):

#### Short Answers:

1. Is there a way to undermine the column width min value?

   - *No. but you can use line shapes to draw a table instead with closer spacing.*
2. How can I create a table that maximises the page "real estate"?

   - *Also by using line shapes instead of a table.*

#### More Information:

You can't undermine the set-out minimum limits of the table settings, this is done by design in Slides.

As a workaround, however, you can 'draw' your own tables out of line Shapes. It's a bit of an ugly workaround, but certainly doable.

There exists a `PageElement` of `Shape` type which you can create to simulate drawing a table. Much like in the UI, you can draw multiple lines and 'stitch' them together with location data.

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/shapes):

> #### Shape
>
> A [`PageElement`](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages#Page.PageElement) kind representing a generic shape that does not have a more specific classification.

#### Example:

[image]

#### References:

- [Shapes | Slides API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/shapes)
- [REST Resource: presentations.pages - `PageElement` | Slides API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages#Page.PageElement)

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, however it does not serve my required purpose. :)